# CSS - Image behaves differently than div

Tags: css, image, flexbox

```css
.d1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4581a99fa5793feaeff38d989a1524c6?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
```

Why does an images also stretch to the very end of a flexbox's width? Shouldn't it only stretch towards the very bottom, like a `div` element does inside a flexbox container?

Comment: It seems that the image you're using "happens" to have an aspect-ratio of 1 / 1, the same as `.d1`. Have you tried this with a, say, 2 / 3 image, like `https://picsum.photos/200/300`?

Answer (score 1):

you can control the maximum width and maximum height of the image, so it can solve your problem easily.

just add `max-width` and `max-height` to the image with CSS, and put your own values to them.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example; if the width of the div content is smaller, it does not take the whole width of the parent by default. Same applies to the image. You need to set a specific width and height otherwise:

```css
.d1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.d1 img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
.d1 div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div>Example Paragraph.</div>
</div>
<div class="d1">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4581a99fa5793feaeff38d989a1524c6?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG">
</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question